# Update UITableViewCell based on alert view button pressed

Tags: uitableview, uibutton, uialertview

I have a tableview with custom cells. Each cell contains a button you press, that prompts an alert.

The alert uses the UIAlertView delegate as expected, and it checks the title of the button to determine what the user pressed. This in turn calls a web service that submits data. Once that submission completes, I need to have the button in that cell change to another button image.

Reloading the data so that it reflects the updates sent to the server and then reloading the tableview is having no effect.

Is there a way to access the cell outside of the cellForRowAtIndexPath? I have it setting a global variable named selectedIndex based on what button I press, but that is as far as I can get. Is it even plausible (or a good idea) to access a cell this way.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: To clarify: it sounds like the issue you're having is that your button isn't changing? Are you using a UIButton in each cell? Can you post your implementation code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are quite a few ways to reload the data in a tableview. But for your case, if you can get a reference to the cell, it would suffice to do little UI related changes(changing images or something like that).

If you think your table's content size is going to vary after the web service returns response, then you must reload the table. Ofcourse you can reload the whole table's content, or just a few rows or sections. Check out the official [documentations](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006943-CH3-SW36) for the detailed information on them

The global variable is not a good way to get the index of the cell, of which button is pressed. A better approach would be if you use the `tag` property of the button. Set the tag of the button with the row(or section whatever your schema is) of indexPath. Then you can fetch the `tag` in your button's selector method.

Get a reference to the cell when the web service call finishes, get an instance of `NSIndexPath` via `indexPathForRow:inSection:`.

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:button.tag inSection:0];
```

Check if the cell is still visible and go forward with that.

```
MyCustomCell *cell = (MyCustomCell *)[self.tblView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

and do your changes on that cell there.

Answer (score 0):

UITableView has a method (not the delegate method) called -cellForRowAtIndexPath:.  Provided that cell is still visible, and you have stored the index path off, you can use that to obtain the cell.  It will return nil if the cell is not visible (but in that case the delegate method will be called later on to provide a cell for that index path again before it becomes visible, so you would configure it then).

The caveats are that a web services call is presumably asynchronous, and lots of things can change between when the user presses the button and you get the web response.  The user could have scrolled the cell offscreen such that it is no longer visible, in which case you would need to store off the updated value somehow so you can properly configure the cell later on.  Also, if your code calls reloadData for any reason, even keeping the NSIndexPath may not make any sense -- if your underlying model has changed at all, the model record associated with the user's click may now be at a completely different NSIndexPath (or may not exist in the data set at all).  Depending on your situation those may or may not be issues, but if they are, it may be best to keep a reference to the selected *record* (or the primary key of that record), and when the call comes back, determine what the index path to that record now is, and see if the cell for that index path is visible.

Lastly, I'd recommend using properties of your view controller to store off these values, not globals.  If you ever create a new instance of the view controller, and you change behavior based on the value of the global variable, it may still be set (with completely bogus values) from the previous usage of that view controller class.